# Plot Rectangle in existing figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a rectangle in my existing figure where I have some points and lines. I don't know why this does not work.
I think the problem refers to the plot calls before.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import json

with open('results_simulation.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


plt.figure('figure1')
for cluster in data['positions']:
    P1_x = cluster[0][0];
    P1_y = cluster[0][1];
    P2_x = cluster[1][0];
    P2_y = cluster[1][1];
    P3_x = cluster[2][0];
    P3_y = cluster[2][1];
    P4_x = cluster[3][0];
    P4_y = cluster[3][1];
    P5_x = cluster[4][0];
    P5_y = cluster[4][1];
    P6_x = cluster[5][0];
    P6_y = cluster[5][1];
    P_X = [P1_x, P4_x, P2_x, P5_x, P3_x, P6_x, P1_x];
    P_Y = [P1_y, P4_y, P2_y, P5_y, P3_y, P6_y, P1_y];
    plt.plot(P_X, P_Y, color='red')
    plt.scatter(P_X, P_Y, s=5, color='black');

plt.grid()
# Tower
plt.plot(0, 0, 'o', markersize=30)

# restricted areas
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
currentAxis = plt.gca()
currentAxis.add_patch(Rectangle((-15, 0), 5, 10,
                      alpha=1, facecolor='none'))

plt.savefig("graph.png", dpi=500)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are creating a new figure when you do `plt.subplots()`, so first remove that. Then you need to provide an edgecolor to your rectangle.

Comment: Thank you very much :)